# Retrieve value from within a div tag in xpath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to retrieve the value in the data-appid field, I have tried using following-sibling but its not really a sibling per se. Not sure how to go about retrieving this. Any pointers will really be great.

```
<div class="section app" data-appid="532054761" data-updateid="10184169">
```

Answer (score 2):

The sibling axis applies to elements, not attributes.

You can reference `data-appid` simply as an attribute of the `div` element.  For example,

```
//div/@data-appid
```

will select `532054761`

If you need to be more specific about the particular `div` element for which you want its `data-appid`, you can use a predicate to select a particular `div` element.  For example:

```
//div[@data-updateid='10184169']/@data-appid
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getAttribute()` method

Try the following code

```
String dataAppId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='section app']")).getAttribute("data-appid");
System.out.println(dataAppId);
```